# Document merge in CiviCase from scheduled activity in timeline

Tags: wordpress, civicase

I've created a case type with a timeline that includes document print/merge activity. Where I am running into issues is with doing the document creation from that timeline generated activity.

When I use the 'Add Activity' drop down in the case manangement I can create a document, use a template, all the things I would expect when using the 'Print/Merge Document' action.

However, when I go to the scheduled activity which was created when the case was created and edit it I can't seeem to do any of those things. I don't have the option to use a  document template or create a document the way I can using the drop down 'add activity' option.

Are activities in case standard timelines just notes/reminders and the actual task has to be done using the dropdown or am I missing something? If I'm not missing something and they are just notes/reminders why set up the timeine/sequence instead of just setting the possible activities.

Answer (score 0):

The print/merge activity type is usually a "system" type that gets created when you use the print/merge search results action, or the Export Document button on Manage Case, not an activity you usually create yourself. The fact that it works from the add activity dropdown seems to be because of some sneaky code that was added to make it do the same as the export document button: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/915e9edd65c7b594372897923734ec52e67f1835/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php#L248-L251